# How to match a number in AWK

Tags: awk

I want to let awk print all the numbers from the input, so I wrote

```
echo 2 1a 12121 -1212 abc | 
awk ' { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /[-.0-9]*/) print $i; } '
```

What I want to say is 'strings consists of '0-9' '.' '-', but in the output it prints every fields out, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/[-.0-9]*/
```

This means zero or more number, `.` or `-`
Since `abc` does contain zero of characters above it will be printed.

Change to `+` meaning one or more:

PS this will also print field with a single `.` and a single `-`

```
echo "2 1a 12121 -1212 abc .  more -  hey 45.62" |  awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/[0-9.-]+/) print $i}'
2
1a
12121
-1212
.
-
45.62
```

---

So I would use some like this to print number only:

```
echo "2 1a 12121 -1212 abc .  more -  hey 45.62" |  awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/^-?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/) print $i}'
2
12121
-1212
45.62
```

`^` Start of field
`-?`contain one `-` or none
`/[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*/`
`[0-9]+` one or more digit
`\.?` 0 or 1 `.`
`[0-9]*` zero or more digits
`$` end of filed

Answer (score 1):

Do you want like this?

```
echo 2 1a 12121 -1212 abc | awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /-?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/) print $i; }'
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but in my command, why would it output thins like 'abc'?